# In Redux, do I need to know instantly which reducers are interested in an action type?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We know that a reducer can choose to process some or all of the action types in an application. An action type is denoted by a string. If I see an action being dispatched, there seems to be no quick way to grasp which reducers will be actively anticipating it. 
If I later come to a previously crafted project and find something not behaving as expected after an action is dispatched, I cannot quickly identify the responsible reducers. The only approach I can think of is to do a folder wide search for the action type.
Is this a real concern? Or is it of little importance to know the responsible reducers?

Comment: Your reasoning is accurate. One way around it is to have your action creators explicitly trigger the actions for functions of other reducers, instead of having the reducer look for the original action creator's types. you can do that with `redux-thunk` or similar middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single reducer, then it is a straight forward answer. However, multiple reducers still connect to a single reducer (i.e. Parent reducer). which you achieve by using the combineReducers of the redux

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
```

this makes everything fetch from the same source. So if you have actionType of "FETCH_BASKET" in basketReducer and you are currently working in salesAction, salesAction can access actionTypes inside basketReducer because they are all from the same source.

> NOTE: Use unique actionType throughout your application to avoid
>   performance issue

we only create reducers for a section of our application to make it easy for us to maintain. I hope this clarifies your doubt